# Object is not loading after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm sure this is simple but I would appreciate any help.

What I have is a page that displays questions and answers.

My model is set up so that the questions (which is actually named survey) nest the answers I want to increment to the next question after submission

What I've done is created a form with a call to a javascript (ajax call back to the update controller) that all works well but when I try to render the partial it does not display and I get no error from the console my update.js.erb is what I want to render

```
 $('#questionarea ul').show().load( "<%= escape_javascript render :partial => "current_question" %> ");
```

the partial _current_question.html.erb is simply ,
      <%= @current_question %>

I have been using chrome to debug from the client side but I don't get any errors and the console is showing normal execution 
Any and all help are appreciated 
I am also adding the html for reference as well as the javascript being called for Ajax as well 
_form.html.erb

```
    <%= form_for @category, remote: true  do |f| %>

<ul id= 'questionarea'> 
<%=@category.surveys.first.question %>
</ul>
<ul>
         <%=hidden_field_tag(:survey_id, @category.surveys.first.survey_id) %>
         <%=hidden_field_tag(:user_id, params[:id]) %>
</ul>
<ul id= 'answerarea'>
    <%= radio_button_tag(:agree , 5) %>
    <%= label_tag(:agree_5, "I completely agree ") %>
    <%= radio_button_tag(:agree , 4) %>
    <%= label_tag(:agree_4, "I agree ") %>
    <%= radio_button_tag(:agree , 3) %>
    <%= label_tag(:agree_3, "I kind of agree ") %>
    <%= radio_button_tag(:agree , 2) %>
    <%= label_tag(:agree_2, "I disagree ") %>
    <%= radio_button_tag(:agree , 1) %>
    <%= label_tag(:agree_1, "I completly disagree ") %>

      This statement is:

    <%= radio_button_tag(:importance , 3) %>
    <%= label_tag(:importance_3, "Incredibly important ") %>
    <%= radio_button_tag(:importance , 2) %>
    <%= label_tag(:importance_2, "Kind of important") %>
    <%= radio_button_tag(:importance , 3) %>
    <%= label_tag(:importance_1, "A good thing to trade for something I care about ") %>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Comments:</li>
       <li><%= text_field_tag :comments %></li>
</ul>

<ul>
<%= f.submit %>
```

My javascript is (form.js)

```
$('.edit_category input[type=submit]').click(function () {
$(this).parent('form').submit();
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: **$('#questionarea ul')** seems to be pointing to nothing, there is no  **ul** tag in your **#questionarea**, I think you meant **$('#questionarea')**

Comment: Thanks that was it really appreciate the quick response I love this site !

Comment: I posted the response so that it is clear that it was the solution. You're welcome by the way : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**$('#questionarea ul')** seems to be pointing to nothing, there is no **ul** tag in your **#questionarea**, I think you meant **$('#questionarea')**